# How to replace outlier after groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of portfolios with risk numbers. I want to groupby by "Port" column in dataframe below and then replace the values in "Risk" column where it is greater than the 95% quantile of its group with the median of that portfolio group

df =

```
    Date           Port       Risk
   2019-04-30        a         21.8
   2019-03-29        a         22.6
   2019-02-28        a         500
   2019-01-31        a         26.1
   2019-04-30        b         36.4
   2019-03-29        b         43.3
   2019-02-28        b         40
   2019-01-31        b         364
```

I tried below code I found on stackoverflow but it doesn't work.

```
def replace(group):
    q = group.quantile(0.95)
    outlier = group>q
    group[outlier] = group.median()
    return group

    df.groupby('Port').transform(replace)
```

Also tried

```
q = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Port')['Risk'].quantile(0.95))
df.loc[(((q.loc[df.Port,'Risk']<df['Risk'].values)))]=q.loc[df.Port,'Risk']
```

Expected result will be to replace the third record of port "a" with median of group "a" which is 22.2 and the fourth record of port "b" with median of group "b" which is 41.6

df =

```
    Date           Port       Risk
   2019-04-30        a         21.8
   2019-03-29        a         22.6
   2019-02-28        a         22.2
   2019-01-31        a         26.1
   2019-04-30        b         36.4
   2019-03-29        b         43.3
   2019-02-28        b         40
   2019-01-31        b         41.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The medians seem to differ slightly with what you're saying (see comment in the output dataframe). Here's one approach using [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

```
g = df.groupby('Port').Risk
df['Risk'] = (df.Risk.where(g.transform('quantile', q=0.95) > df.Risk, 
                            g.transform('median')))
```

---

```
      Date     Port  Risk
0  2019-04-30    a  21.80
1  2019-03-29    a  22.60
2  2019-02-28    a  24.35 # -> np.median([21.8, 22.6, 500, 26.1]) = 24.35
3  2019-01-31    a  26.10
4  2019-04-30    b  36.40
5  2019-03-29    b  43.30
6  2019-02-28    b  40.00
7  2019-01-31    b  41.65
```

Comment: thanks for the code. This works perfectly. Quick logic question, since we are checking to replace numbers where risk > 95th percentile by the median, why is the where function set up to check 95% quantile array > risk? shouldnt it be df.risk>g.transform(quantile, q = 0.95). the code works and gives the desired result but just the intuition is a little confusing

Comment: Oh this is dues to the fact that `where` replaces where the result is False @sudhasethu. Your welcome :) Don't forget to accept if it helped (green check under voting ticks)

Comment: Thanks Yatu. This was very helpful

Answer (score 3):

To stick to the code you posted:

```
def replace(group):
    q = group.quantile(0.95)
    outlier = group>q
    group[outlier] = group.median()
    return group

df['Risk'] = (df.groupby('Port').transform(replace))
print(df)
```

output:

```
         Date Port   Risk
0  2019-04-30    a  21.80
1  2019-03-29    a  22.60
2  2019-02-28    a  24.35
3  2019-01-31    a  26.10
4  2019-04-30    b  36.40
5  2019-03-29    b  43.30
6  2019-02-28    b  40.00
7  2019-01-31    b  41.65
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Port" : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b' ,'b'],
    "Risk" : [21.8, 22.6, 500, 26.1, 36.4,43.3,40,364]
})

for port in df['Port'].unique():
    mask_port = df['Port'] == port
    quantile_port = df[mask_port].quantile(0.95)
    median_port = df[mask_port].median()
    df.loc[(mask_port) & (df['Risk']>quantile_port.Risk), 'Risk'] = median_port.Risk

In [1] : print(df)
Out[1] :   Port   Risk
0    a  21.80
1    a  22.60
2    a  24.35
3    a  26.10
4    b  36.40
5    b  43.30
6    b  40.00
7    b  41.65
```